# how to load magnific popup modal on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, magnific-popup

I'm trying to load my magnific popup modal on page load, however I can't quite understand the syntax in the documentation. How do I call the modal on page load?

My HTML:

```
<div id="test-modal" class"white-popup-block mfp-hide">
    <h1>Modal Test</h1>
    <p>
    Test Some text.
    </p>
    <p>
    <a class="popup-modal-dismiss">Dismiss</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
$(window).load(function(){

???? What code should I place???
});
```

I have already preloaded the script and css files, what do I type inside the JS to make it load the popup on load?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
    items: {
        src: '<div id="test-modal" class="white-popup"><h1>Modal Test</h1><p>Test Some text.</p><p><a class="popup-modal-dismiss">Dismiss</a></p></div>',
        type:'inline'
    },
    modal: true
});
```

And the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upLXb/1/)...

Comment: Is there a way to open a popup with existing markup? I already have the DOM elements setup, I just want to be able to open the popup with JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

```
$.magnificPopup.open({items: {src: '#id-of-your-popup'},type: 'inline'}, 0);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
    $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
            src: 'images/loading.gif',
            type:'image'
        },
        modal: true
    });
```