# magnific popup how to open popup via script just like as alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I have a div with contents to be displayed as popup, however, I am not sure how to open it in a popup using magnific popup script automatically, just like as an alert.

```
$(function () {
    $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
      type: 'inline',
      focus: '#zipCode',
      modal: true
    });
  });
```

when I fired the div with class "popup-modal" using click event, I am seeing screen with gray color having value rendered as true.

Comment: Yesterday I answered a similar question: [How to load magnific popup modal on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507900/how-to-load-magnific-popup-modal-on-page-load/20508561#20508561)